# Boolean from cookie in Twig

Tags: symfony, cookies, boolean, twig

When my site launches I have a simple js script that detects if the site is viewed on a high resolution device, then it saves the value to a cookie.

```
{% if app.request.cookies.has('d_p_r') %}
    {% set retina = app.request.cookies.get('d_p_r') %}
{% else %}
    {% set retina = false %}
    <script> ... </script>
{% endif %}
```

I check that my retina value has been set outputting {{ retina }} somewhere in my site, and it is returning 'false' on my computer, and 'true' on my iPad. So far, so good.

The problem is when I try to access the boolean value.

```
{% if retina == true %}
    <img alt="{{ alt }}" src="{{ ('img/' ~ img)|imagine_filter(filter) }}">
{% else %}
    {% if big is defined %}
    <img  alt="{{ alt }}" src="{{ asset('img/' ~ img) }}">
    {% else %}
    <img alt="{{ alt }}" src="{{ ('img/' ~ img)|imagine_filter(filter ~ '@2x') }}">
    {% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

The {% if retina == true %} is not working right. If I change it to == false, I generate retina pictures everywhere. It's as if it's always returning true, despite the value of {{ retina }} returning false.

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong here. I tried doing just {% if retina %} but that didn't help. I have also cleared my cache between all attempts at fixing this.

Comment: Are you sure `app.request.cookies.get('d_p_r')` returns `bool(true)` ? Can you try `{{ dump(retina) }}` ? You may also want to try with `{% if retina is not empty %}`

Comment: It returns true or false, I'm outputting the value in my site, and it is detecting wether I'm on my computer or iPad correctly.

Comment: Ok, upon rereading your comment, I tried a dump(retina).It returned string(5) "false".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `retina` is a string — not a boolean. Cookies are just strings and do not support types. And `$nonEmtpyString == true` is always `true`. So, you could do `retina == 'true'` instead.

But if you want a boolean in your templates, you could do this:

```
{% set retina = app.request.cookies.get('d_p_r') == 'true' ? true : false %}
```

Comment: Would it be too much to ask which one is faster? The code will be repeated several times on some sites. Also thanks a lot, this was so obvious.

Comment: You should not bother with performance in this case. Go with the solution that conveys the meaning of your code in the most clear manner. There will be much more problematic performance issues in your code if you profile it.